# How to compute tight asymptotic bounds for the recurrence

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

T(n) = 2/3T(n/2) + 3T(n/3) + 8T(n/4)

I tried computing it, but I am confused when there are multiple recurrences.

Comment: Master's theorem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method